# Roslyn runtime compile scripts with Linq => error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm using the Roslyn compiler to runtime compile C# scripts (.NET 4.8 Project).
As soon as the script contains a Linq expression, I get the following compile error:

```
Compiler Error => ./scripts/65c2ea54b62241f49b7bf1a3f486bd01.cs(395,25): error CS0012: The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
```

I'm unsure how to add the corresponding "netstandard" reference(s) to resolve the compile error.
I tried to add:

```
compilation.AddReferences(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Assembly.Load("netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0").Location));
```

But this fails with:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0' or one of its dependencies
```

Comment: I think you need System.ValueTuple.dll

Comment: I do have ValueTuple referenced actually - this is in respect to ValueType and seems to require a different reference

Comment: Do you have a reference to netstandard.dll 2.0.0.0?